# Media player only works as administrator?

Tags: windows-media-player, media-player

It seems I can only get Media Player 12 to work as administrator.  If I run it normally (I am in the administrator group on my local PC) and right click on Music, and choose Manage Music Library. Media Player will sit and think for 5 or so seconds, then just not do anying, no dialog, no error.

If I run as administator I can now get into the Manage Music Library dialog and add my a public folder containing my music.  I've even tried granting everyone access to the public folder.

One thing to note is that I have recently set up a domain controller and added my PC to the domain.  With my local account I never noticed this problem, but I've since created a domain account and am now seeing this issue.  I can't find much difference between the local and domain accounts - both are in the administrator group.  Why would WMP require run as administrator?

OS, Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0):

> One thing to note is that I have
>   recently set up a domain controller
>   and added my PC to the domain.

This seems to be your problem, the wmp tries to check the network for media folders. I think you normal user does not have the privileges to access the network.

Comment: My local and my domain user both do have access to the network.